# Frameworks/Charts.framework no identity found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have no idea now with below strange error, in my target, I could find my **Code Signing** `iPhone Distribution: Easy to play (Shanghai) Network Technology Co., Ltd. (P2J3XCDYM7)`.

[image]

while in my **Pods** project I can't find above **Code signing**, like below image show.

[image]

so finally I always get below error when building.

```
Code Signing /Users/mengwenqiaoxindongcom/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tyrantdb_client_ios-gbphllmpdxktitcoebgjmxzphcku/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TapDB.app/Frameworks/Charts.framework with Identity iPhone Distribution: Easy to play (Shanghai) Network Technology Co., Ltd. (P2J3XCDYM7)
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 85FDFF4D7DC1674430B7B3B33A8339633A6C4ABF  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements "/Users/mengwenqiaoxindongcom/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tyrantdb_client_ios-gbphllmpdxktitcoebgjmxzphcku/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TapDB.app/Frameworks/Charts.framework"
85FDFF4D7DC1674430B7B3B33A8339633A6C4ABF: no identity found
```

I don't know why I can't select the same **Code Sign** as second image show.
any idea?  thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You have selected `Don't Code Sign` option. Select `iPhone Developer` there and the option should show itself.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, I try it but failed with same error :(

Comment: What version of XCode are you using?

Comment: I use XCode `v7.3.1`